# Convert Dataframe to List of Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I want to convert my dataframe to list of elements.
Right now, I have a pandas dataframe below:

```
my_df = {'Column_1': ['1|4', '3|9', '15|18']}

Column_1
"1|4"
"3|9"
"15|18"
```

I want to convert this dataframe column into list of elements, like below:

```
my_list = [[1,4], [3,9], [15,18]]
```

How do I do this? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Are always 2 values after split? In another words, there is same number of separators, like here one `|` for each element?

Answer (score 3):

You can split the column on `|`, expanding it to separate columns, then convert those to integers. Then you can convert the resultant dataframe into a nested list:

```py
my_df = {'Column_1': ['1|4', '3|9', '15|18']}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_df)
out = df['Column_1'].str.split('|', expand=True).astype(int).values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4], [3, 9], [15, 18]]
```

Note that if you only want strings in the output (as described in the title of the question), the code can be much simpler:

```py
out = df['Column_1'].str.split('|').tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['1', '4'], ['3', '9'], ['15', '18']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with convert splitted values to integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_df)

L = [[int(y) for y in x.split('|')] for x in df['Column_1']]
```

Or:

```
L = [list(map(int, x.split('|'))) for x in df['Column_1']]

print (L)
[[1, 4], [3, 9], [15, 18]]
```

Solutions working if different number of separators:

```
my_df = {'Column_1': ['1|4', '3|9', '15|18|45']}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_df)


L = [[int(y) for y in x.split('|')] for x in df['Column_1']]

L = [list(map(int, x.split('|'))) for x in df['Column_1']]
print (L)
[[1, 4], [3, 9], [15, 18, 45]]
```

Slow pandas solution:

```
L = (df['Column_1'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=0)
                  .agg(list).tolist())
print (L)
[[1, 4], [3, 9], [15, 18, 45]]
```

---

If always 2 values after split:

```
L = [list(x) for x in df['Column_1'].str.split('|', expand=True).astype('int').to_numpy()]
```